# if #available(iOS 14.0, *) { }

Tags: ios, swift

```
if #available(iOS 14.0, *) { ... }
```

When I import Deployment Info in Xcode to iOS13, it works, but the simulator has iOS14 version. This is messing with my head. Does this function work on iPhone 6s (iOS13) without iOS 14 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#available(, *)` function is implemented for all iOS versions.

Think like the first argument is just a double value.

If current version is less than first argument value, it returns false.

Inside that if is call of iOS 14+ available function. Compiled program just "believes" it to be available that's why without that `if` it would crash on iOS 13- device.